# perfect square including both end values

Tags: perfect-square

I am trying to obtain all the perfect squares between two values(both included).
I tried the following code which gives me the count excluding the end values.

cin>>a>>b;
n=(int)sqrt(b)-sqrt(a);

**How can i get the count of perfect squares including the end values?**

Comment: Well the end values may not be perfect squares, but if you are making the assumption that both a and b are perfect squares, why not just add 2 to `n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add boundary condition to your logic

how to fish - Pseudo code here

1. n starts with 0
2. if a || b is perfect square, n++
3. n += (int)(sqrt(b) - sqrt(a))
4. return n

fish - [here is the answer](http://comproguide.blogspot.kr/2014/04/counting-number-of-perfect-squares-in.html)